# Stopwatch React.js application, with immediate reset/re-start timer on a single button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, setinterval

to study React.js I started converting javascript projects.

In this project, a startup button will trigger a setTimeout() function for 3 seconds before it triggers the closing function

```
let timer= false;
let rando= null;
let conta= 0;
let punteggio= 0;

startup.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    timer= true

    rando= Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000)
    centrato.innerText= rando

    challenge()
})

function challenge(){
    if(timer && conta< 300){

        conta ++
        setTimeout(challenge, 10)

    }else if(conta== 300){
        perso()
    }else{
        perso()
    }
}
```

Then I have 2 buttons, one will reset the setTimeout() function **and** will record the time passed before the click, and the other will stop the setTimeout()

```
tre.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    if( rando% 3== 0 ){
        vinto()
    }else{
        timer= false
    }
})

notre.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    if(rando% 3== 0){
        timer= false
    }else{
        vinto()
    }
})

function vinto(){
    punteggio+= conta
    conta= 0;
    rando= Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000)
}

function perso(){
    risultato.innerText= "You got " + giri + " numbers in " + punteggio/100 + " seconds"
    punteggio= 0;
    conta= 0;
}
```

Using **useState()** and **useEffect()** on React.js I could get a reset/restart stopwatch by clicking twice or a reset/restart on a single button but being unable to stop the timer, I also tried setInterval().
I need the user to click only once to reset and repeat the setTimeout() and also to be able to stop the timer on a button click, **on React.js** code.

You can check the complete codepen [HERE]https://codepen.io/misterlinux/pen/yLRBMNx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain a stop/reset/re-start single button in react you will need useEffect.

```
<button onClick={ ()=> setIsActive((x)=> !x) }>
  start
</button>
<button onClick={reset}>
  Reset
</button>
```

You will need 2 variables, one for the timer event listener, and another for the timer counter.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let interval = null;
  if (isActive) {

    interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
    }, 500);

  } else if (!isActive && seconds !== 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    setSeconds(0)
    setIsActive(!isActive);
  }
  
  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, [isActive, seconds]);

function reset() {
  setSeconds(0);
  setIsActive(false);
}
```

The **useEffect() hook** synchronizes a component with an external variable, we start the setInterval() after the isActive useState() changes.

By changing the isActive again we stop the setInterval(), we then reset the seconds counter and change the useEffect() dependency to start it again.

If you want to completely stop the setInterval() you can use a separate function to stop and reset it.

Answer (score 0):

Canceling a [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) needs to be done with [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout).

E.g.:

```
let timeoutId = setTimeout( function(){}, 1000 );
clearTimeout( timeoutId );
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, do you have any tips on how to obtain the starting javascript timeout() function buttons in Reactjs?

Comment: Obtain it where ? Which "timeout()" function ? _(you don't have a function called "timeout" in your code)_. You also don't have any [React](https://react.dev/) code, at least not visible to me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am asking how to obtain the javascript result using Reactjs, I said what I tried to do and how it didn't work in the question.